How do I copy the electrs index to a new node without it having to reindex?
I have electrs installed on an old Umbrel bitcoin node, and I want to copy it to new hardware (with Umbrel as well), instead of having electrs reindex the blockchain from scratch, which can take over a day to complete.
Do I just copy the electrs/data/ directory to the new node?

I tried it and the answer is that indeed copying the directory does work, so it didn't need to reindex the whole thing.
There's also the same answer online that I found on github:
https://github.com/romanz/electrs/discussions/1010
